# Mysql subquery or something better

Tags: mysql

I am somewhat new to mysql and I am having an issue on how I should best write the following query. Say I have a table that has a `datetime` column as well as a few others I want to search on. Since this is just one table, I don't think a join statement would be appropriate here (but I may be wrong since I have not done much in the way of join statements) and I think a subquery is what I need here. So my initial query is to search the table based on a search string the user entered and then I want to limit that on a datetime (start date and end date) also specified by the user in an HTML form.

Table Schema

```
id, datetime, host, level, message
```

I want to select any rows that contain $searchstring first so something like ...

```
SELECT * FROM $table WHERE (level LIKE '%$searchstring%') OR (message LIKE '%$searchstring%') LIMIT $offset,$limit
```

If I want to limit the above results also by the `datetime` column, the query would look something like this ...

```
SELECT * FROM $table WHERE (datetime >='$startdate') AND (datetime < '$enddate')
```

How can I best merge these queries into one so I can first get any rows that match the search query and then further limit the rows by the start and end datetime?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using a single where condition. 
In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ((level LIKE '%$searchstring%') OR (message LIKE '%$searchstring%')) AND (datetime >='$startdate') AND (datetime < '$enddate') LIMIT $offset,$limit
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I was under the impression I would need 2 queries but now that I see this, it makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a `JOIN` but only add a condition

```
SELECT * 
FROM $table 
WHERE (level LIKE '%$searchstring%' OR message LIKE '%$searchstring%')
AND
datetime >='$startdate'
AND datetime < '$enddate'
LIMIT $offset,$limit
```